# Custom UITableViewCell Looses Content when Scrolling through TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with several custom cells, two of which contain imageviews. When they are populated with images, they are fine, but if I scroll the tableview down, so that the imageviews are out of view, and then back, the images disappear, leaving them blank white.

```
CellForRowAtIndexPath Method

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *GECIdentifier = @"GECell";
static NSString *TECIdentifier = @"TECell";
static NSString *AMCIdentifier = @"AMCell";

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    //Create generic GEC for use by all rows in section
    GeneralEditingCell *GEC = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:GECIdentifier];
    if (GEC == nil) {
        GEC = [[GeneralEditingCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        GEC.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        GEC.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        GEC.master = self;
    }

    //Create and setup datepicker and dateformatter for later use
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.tag = indexPath.row;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"LLL dd, yyyy"];

    //Configure each cell individually
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            if (editing) {
                GEC.titleField.text = [item objectForKey:@"Title"];
                GEC.dateField.text = [item objectForKey:@"Date"];
                GEC.imageView.image = [self getThumbnailforVideoAtPath:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[item objectForKey:@"Video Path"]]];
            } else {
                GEC.dateField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
                GEC.dateField.inputView = datePicker;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return GEC;
}

if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    //Create generic TEC for use by all rows in section
    TextEditingCell *TEC = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TECIdentifier];
    if (TEC == nil) {
        TEC = [[TextEditingCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        TEC.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        TEC.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    //Configure each cell individually
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            if (editing) {
                TEC.textField.text = @"Editing Mode";
            } else {
                TEC.label.text = @"TextEdit Cell";
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return TEC;
}

if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    //Create generic AMC for use by all rows in section
    AddMediaCell *AMC = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AMCIdentifier];
    if (AMC == nil) {
        AMC = [[AddMediaCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        AMC.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        AMC.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    //Configure each cell individually
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            AMC.label.text = @"Add Video";
            break;
        case 1:
            AMC.label.text = @"Add Photos";
            break;
        case 2:
            AMC.label.text = @"Record Audio";
            break;
        case 3:
            AMC.label.text = @"Add Text Note";
            break;
        case 4:
            AMC.label.text = @"Attach Location";
            break;
        case 5:
            AMC.label.text = @"Attach Weather Data";
            break;
        case 6:
            AMC.label.text = @"Add More Tags";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return AMC;
}

//Catch any previously unhandled cell
UITableViewCell *errorCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (errorCell == nil) {
    errorCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
errorCell.textLabel.text = @"ERROR! UNHANDLED CELL!!!";
return errorCell;
}
```

Comment: When you allocate the cells if they come up `nil`, why don't you use their category identifier rather than the generic `CellIdentifier`?

Answer (score 0):

You only show one use of imageView, but perhaps this modification will fix that and be instructive as well. THe idea is for any property in your cell subclass, you cannot assume what any given property might be showing. So for each one either set it or clear it:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        if (editing) {
            GEC.titleField.text = [item objectForKey:@"Title"];
            GEC.dateField.text = [item objectForKey:@"Date"];
            GEC.dateField.inputView = nil;
            GEC.imageView.image = [self getThumbnailforVideoAtPath:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[item objectForKey:@"Video Path"]]];
        } else {
            GEC.titleField.text = @"";
            GEC.dateField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
            GEC.dateField.inputView = datePicker;
            GEC.imageView.image = nil; 
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (data doesn't retain when scrolling around) but mine was a index miscount that had cells displaying nothing.

What helped me debug it was:

- set a break in `cellForRowAtIndexPath'
- disable it
- run the app and scroll down
- enable the breakpoint again
- scroll back up

`UITableView` automatically free's memory on off screen `UITableViewCell` rows and calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again when you scroll back up.

You probably missed a case where you only initialize the `UIImageView` for each row once but when you call it again something goes awry.